# Signature below listings

Tags: listings

How can I put automatic signature below my code listings. Now I put my code listings like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
MY CODE
\end{lstlisting}
```

Settings of listings:

```
    \usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  numbers=left,
  frame=single,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
  keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
  stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by "automatic signature"?

Comment: Maybe some kind of caption would do what you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to make caption below listing and finally I would like to make table of contents - listings

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Customizing_captions) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `caption` key to obtain the captions; use `captionpos=b` so that the captions appear below the listing (the default position is above).  The command `\lstlistoflistings` gives you a list of all listings for which you declared a caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  numbers=left,
  frame=single,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
  commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
  keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
  stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={this is some description of the first listing}]
MY CODE
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={this is some description of the second listing}]
MY CODE
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={this is some description of the third listing}]
MY CODE
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]